# Problems with Jquery fadeIn, fadeOut, delay(),

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

This is probably asked a million times, but I still cannot make it work: Whenever I use Jquery, the fadeIn(), fadeOut(), and delay()-functions doesn't work for some reason. I'm not a professional in Jquery, but I've used it a lot.

I want to make a tooltip-like div, whenever I hover over the box, it appears some time after with a fading effect. I implement my JS/ Juery at the bottom of the body (which should work), but I'm also using the Twitter Bootstrap css and it's starter template.

```js
var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax')
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  // mouse coordinates
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
});

$('.me').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).mousemove(function() {
    // show tooltip
    $('.pointer').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
    $('.pointer').css({
      left: mouseX,
      top: mouseY
    });
  });
}).mouseout(function() {
  // hide tooltip
  $('.pointer').fadeOut('slow');
});

$(function() {
  $('.me').click(function() {
    console.log('Click..');
    window.location = "#about_me";
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.hero-image,
.front,
.name,
.portfolio,
.click_me {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("hero.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.front {
  background: url("front_png8.png") no-repeat 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.me {
  width: 285px;
  height: 790px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16%;
  left: 65%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.me:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.name {
  background: url("name.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 70%;
  top: 18%;
}

.click_me {
  background: url("click_me.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 10%
}

.portfolio {
  background: url("portfolio.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 70%;
  top: 14%;
}

.whitespace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 10ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image"></div>
<div class="rellax portfolio" data-rellax-speed="4"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
<div class="rellax click_me" data-rellax-speed="-3"></div>
<div class="rellax name" data-rellax-speed="8"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="whitespace"></div>
<div class="pointer"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="about_me">
    <h2></h2>
    <p>
      16 Jan 1999 I am a IT-student at Thomas More Kempen. In my spare time I play the guitar and piano and I love going out with friends. Motivation When I graduate, I would like to work for a company in the programming sector to show my creativity and designing
      skills. My dream is to become a game developer and I would like to start my own company.

    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea ipsum iste molestiae natus quidem? Aut consequuntur doloribus eos ex expedita fugit illo iste maxime neque, officia perferendis quae quia quisquam temporibus vel veniam, voluptates! Culpa
      dignissimos dolores eius eveniet, expedita ipsam, laudantium magni nostrum numquam recusandae repudiandae, ut vel! Accusamus accusantium amet aperiam blanditiis deleniti dignissimos esse est explicabo facere illum, ipsam iusto laboriosam laborum
      libero maiores modi, neque nisi odit officia porro possimus praesentium provident quasi quia quis quos reiciendis repellendus repudiandae saepe, tempora vel vero voluptate voluptates. Commodi, culpa doloribus in numquam quam sequi tenetur! Cum et,
      placeat?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.12.1/rellax.min.js" integrity="sha256-+xf9aJnHocnmrigq2hIDJGBSAnJdF5NH+Ooe5J2PHiI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have made a **fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/Nick_Sch/yupxbq5r/5/ (first time using a fiddle..)

Comment: The errors are because you're loading two versions of jQuery. The second one, which overrides the first, is the `slim` version which doesn't have any animation or AJAX methods. Remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If I paste all my JS/Jquery in a linked js-file, will it still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have two versions of jQuery, should pick one.

You might want to use `event` properties on Mouse Over. I like to use `.hover()` instead.

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
  $('.me').click(function() {
    console.log('Click..');
    window.location = "#about_me";
  }).hover(function(e) {
      // show tooltip
      $(".pointer").fadeOut(1, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".pointer").css({
            left: e.pageX + "px",
            top: e.pageY + "px"
          }).fadeIn("slow");
        }, 2000);
      });
    },
    function(e) {
      // hide tooltip
      $('.pointer').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.hero-image,
.front,
.name,
.portfolio,
.click_me {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("hero.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.front {
  background: url("front_png8.png") no-repeat 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.me {
  width: 285px;
  height: 790px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16%;
  left: 65%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.me:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.name {
  background: url("name.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 70%;
  top: 18%;
}

.click_me {
  background: url("click_me.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 10%
}

.portfolio {
  background: url("portfolio.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 70%;
  top: 14%;
}

.whitespace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 10ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.12.1/rellax.min.js" integrity="sha256-+xf9aJnHocnmrigq2hIDJGBSAnJdF5NH+Ooe5J2PHiI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="hero-image"></div>
<div class="rellax portfolio" data-rellax-speed="4"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
<div class="rellax click_me" data-rellax-speed="-3"></div>
<div class="rellax name" data-rellax-speed="8"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="whitespace"></div>
<div class="pointer"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="about_me">
    <h2></h2>
    <p>16 Jan 1999 I am a IT-student at Thomas More Kempen. In my spare time I play the guitar and piano and I love going out with friends. Motivation When I graduate, I would like to work for a company in the programming sector to show my creativity and
      designing skills. My dream is to become a game developer and I would like to start my own company.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea ipsum iste molestiae natus quidem? Aut consequuntur doloribus eos ex expedita fugit illo iste maxime neque, officia perferendis quae quia quisquam temporibus vel veniam, voluptates! Culpa
      dignissimos dolores eius eveniet, expedita ipsam, laudantium magni nostrum numquam recusandae repudiandae, ut vel! Accusamus accusantium amet aperiam blanditiis deleniti dignissimos esse est explicabo facere illum, ipsam iusto laboriosam laborum
      libero maiores modi, neque nisi odit officia porro possimus praesentium provident quasi quia quis quos reiciendis repellendus repudiandae saepe, tempora vel vero voluptate voluptates. Commodi, culpa doloribus in numquam quam sequi tenetur! Cum et,
      placeat?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

See More: https://api.jquery.com/hover/